# IntentService is freezing my application UI

Tags: java, android, user-interface, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my application, I am using Intentservice to fetch the data from server and store fetched data in to local sqlite db. I am using 5 IntentService to fetch and fill five tables. Data may up to 300 rows for each Intent Service. What should I do?

IntentService Code:

```
public class SendBpRecordServer extends IntentService {

    DbHelper dbHelper;
    public static final String TAG="BP Service";
    public JSONObject finalData;


    public SendBpRecordServer() {
        super("BP");
        dbHelper=new DbHelper(this);
        Log.i("In Constructor",TAG);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String recName=intent.getStringExtra("nameTag");

        if (recName.equals("fetch"))
        {
            Log.i("Send Data","Yes");
            fetchDatFromServer();

            ResultReceiver resultReceiver=intent.getParcelableExtra("receiverTagBP");

            Log.d("BP Reseult ",resultReceiver.toString());

            Bundle bun= new Bundle();
            bun.putBoolean("Process_Complete_bp",true);
            resultReceiver.send(2, bun);

        }
        else {
            Log.i("Inside Service PUT BP ","Yes");
            dataCollected();

        }


    }


    private void fetchDatFromServer() {

        Response.Listener listener=new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                Log.i("Json Array Response", response.toString());

                try
                {
                    Boolean responseStatusCondition=response.getBoolean("success");

                    if (responseStatusCondition)
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("response");

                        Log.i("Array Size is",Integer.toString(jsonArray.length()));

                        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                            //Set the flag bit to 1 since data is already at server
                            long result=dbHelper.insertIntoBloodPressureDetails(childJSONObject.getInt("systolic"), childJSONObject.getInt("diastolic"),  childJSONObject.getLong("timestamp"),1 );

                           // Log.i("Insertion result ",Long.toString(result));
                        }

                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                        //This is midnight time in GMT
                        long unixTimeStamp = c.getTimeInMillis();

                        //Convert it in to Indian time System
                        long indianMidNightTime=unixTimeStamp-19800000;

                        //Log.i("Now Calculates Days","doing");
                        dbHelper.calculateDays(dbHelper.bpTableName, dbHelper.bpCOLUMN_days, dbHelper.bpCOLUMN_timestamp, indianMidNightTime);


                    }



                }catch (JSONException js)
                {
                    js.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


        };


        Response.ErrorListener errorListener=new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                //   Handle Error
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " this Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    //TODO
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User not authorized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null)
                {
                    try {
                        String res = new String(response.data,
                                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                        // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                        obj.put("New Error",res);

                        Log.i("New Server Error",obj.toString());
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                        // Couldn't properly decode data to string
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e2) {
                        // returned data is not JSONObject?
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    //TODO
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    //TODO
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error consuming request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else error.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        String bp_url=Constants.url+"bp";

        JsonObjectHeader customRequest=new JsonObjectHeader(bp_url, null, listener, errorListener);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(customRequest);


    }

    private void dataCollected() {

        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();

        ArrayList<Graph> arrayList=dbHelper.fetchDataFromBp();

        for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
        {
            Graph graph=new Graph();

            graph=arrayList.get(i);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

                jsonObject.put("systolic",graph.getHeight());
                jsonObject.put("diastolic",graph.getWeight());
                jsonObject.put("timestamp",graph.getTime());

                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
            }catch (JSONException js)
            {
                js.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        finalData=new JSONObject();

        try {
            finalData.put("bp",jsonArray);
        }catch (JSONException js)
        {
            js.printStackTrace();
        }

        sendDatatoServer();

    }


    private void sendDatatoServer()
    {

        Response.Listener listener=new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    // Parsing json object response
                    // response will be a json object

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Boolean responseStatusCondition = response.getBoolean("success");
                    Log.i("Response BP",responseStatusCondition.toString());

                    if (responseStatusCondition)
                        dbHelper.setTheFlagBpTable();
                    else
                        Log.i("Something Went Wrong"," On Server");



                }
                catch (JSONException k)
                {
                    Log.i("On Response",k.getMessage());
                    k.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
        };


        Response.ErrorListener errorListener=new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                //   Handle Error
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " this Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    //TODO
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User not authorized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    //TODO
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    //TODO
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    //TODO
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error consuming request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else error.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        Log.i("Bp Final Data",finalData.toString());

        JsonObjectHeader customRequest=new JsonObjectHeader(Request.Method.PUT, Constants.url+"bp", finalData, listener, errorListener);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(customRequest);
    }


}
```

Code to call intentservice:

```
Log.i("Fetch BP Data ", SendBpRecordServer.TAG);
            resultReceiverBP=new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());
            resultReceiverBP.setReceiver(this);

            Log.i("Bp resultreceiver ",resultReceiverBP.toString());

             Intent intent2=new Intent(this,SendBpRecordServer.class);
             intent2.putExtra("nameTag","fetch");
             intent2.putExtra("receiverTagBP",resultReceiverBP);
             startService(intent2);
```

and intent send me the code when it complete the task

In the onReceiveResult.. resultcode is send through the calling intentservice and when the count goes to 5 then lauching the mainactivity(although this trick is not working i.e. launching mainactivity without complete the task assigned to intentservice).

```
@Override
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("Diabetes","received result from Service= "+resultData.getString("ServiceTag"));
       // Log.d("BMI ","received result from Service= "+resultData.getString("ServiceTag"));

       /* if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }*/

        Log.i("Get Values ",Integer.toString(Constants.getValues));

        if (resultCode==0 && resultData.getBoolean("Process_Complete"))
            Constants.getValues++;

        if (resultCode==1 && resultData.getBoolean("Process_Complete_bmi"))
            Constants.getValues++;

        if (resultCode==2 && resultData.getBoolean("Process_Complete_bp"))
            Constants.getValues++;

        if (resultCode==3 && resultData.getBoolean("Process_Complete_med_stats"))
            Constants.getValues++;

        if (resultCode==4 && resultData.getBoolean("Process_Complete_one"))
            Constants.getValues++;



        if (Constants.getValues==5)
        {
            Constants.getValues=0;
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Down voters..Plz give him suggestion before down vote the any question....@Ankur , here in SO , you have to provide brief descrption before asking any question here...Plz let me know yours code and crashes or error u are facing now

Comment: the problem should be in your code. You did something wrong.

Comment: I have updated the code @RavindraKushwaha.. I am not getting any error but app is freezing with the error msg app is stop to responding... the root cause of this is to updating the db using intent service

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal ..For updating the question +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you absolutely certain that it's the `IntentService` that is the root cause of the UI freezes? Intent services are specially designed to run in worker threads in order to offload processing from the main (UI) thread, with one of the main reasons for this being to help *prevent* UI freezes.

Perhaps try starting your debugging efforts at the UI level. In particular, what provides the `ResultReceiver` to the `IntentService` when you start it, and what do you do in the `onReceiveResult` callback method in that receiver instance?

Other than that, for the activity which you're experiencing the freezes in, check what kind of operations you're taking. Loading large amounts of data from a database on the main thread (i.e. without using a `Loader` or something similar to offload the processing to a worker thread) is a common cause of UI freezes, at least in my experience so far.

**Update**

I think I've worked out what the problem is. There are two main issues, both stemming from how you're using Volley. When you add a request to the Volley queue, it gets executed asynchronously. That means that the `queue` method returns immediately. In your intent service code, this means that the service immediately goes on to tell the `ResultReceiver` that it has finished processing, when actually all it has done is queue the request. All five intent services will do this, meaning that `MainActivity` will be entered into very quickly. This is the first issue.

The second issue explains the freeze you're experiencing. Although Volley executes requests on worker threads, it returns the parsed responses to requests on the main thread - see the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#simple). This means that all the response processing you're doing in the intent service (putting the data into the database, etc.) is actually happening on the main (UI) thread. This explains the freezing.

What you probably want to do here is switch over to using Volley's `RequestFuture` instead. This basically turns an asynchronous request into a synchronous one by allowing you to block until the request finishes. To do this, create a future of the appropriate type (`JSONObject` in your case) and set it as both the listener and error listener for the request. Then, queue the request as you do now, and immediately afterward call call the `get` method on the future. This method will block until the response has finished processing. It's okay to do this in an intent service because it runs on a worker thread, not the UI thread.

If the request succeeds you'll get the data returned and you can execute all of the logic which is currently in your `Response.Listener` implementation. If an error occurs (i.e. the request fails for some reason), the request future will throw an exception which you can handle to take any appropriate actions.

Using request futures is quite a different approach to using listeners and you may need to change your code quite a bit to get it to work, but it should resolve the issues that you're seeing.

Hope that helps, and my sincere apologies for not picking up on the bug earlier.

Comment: in my Intent service I am fetching data, storing it into db and doing updating of the data also.. Since out of all this updating is taking too much time and it is freezing the main UI.                                                           Ya I am pretty sure it is happening due to intent service because other than intent service I am doing nothing.

Comment: So if you comment out the code which starts all of the `IntentService`s, the UI doesn't freeze? Also, what happens if you modify your code so that only one of the five `IntentService`s that you mentioned is run?

Comment: If I comment out intent code it is working fine. Even I have small data to process like 20 rows to each it is working perfectly fine. But as data increases it start freezes.  I run only one Intent service with 273 rows it works perfectly fine

Comment: In that case it seems that chaining your calls to the services (e.g. starting the next service only once the currently running one has finished) could be a potential solution. Is there any particular need to run them all at the same time?

Comment: all intentservice are mutually exclusive... but before starting the app all should be run

Comment: Would you mind posting the code which shows how and where you're starting your intent services? I think that'd be the easiest way to help further.

Comment: Thanks. A couple of extra questions ... you mentioned 5 intent services in your question - I only see one? Also, where is the code that you just posted (an Activity subclass, an Application subclass, etc.)? Finally, the `ResultReceiver`'s receiver is set to `this`. What does the `onReceiveResult` override code look like?

Comment: other intent service are doing same work so same code. no I have posted that code only... onReceiveResult code is updated in the question.

Comment: Okay, so let me check my understanding. You have some kind of activity which implements `ResultReceiver` and at some point starts five separate intent services, passing itself as the ResultReceiver in the intent used to start each one? While the services are running you show a progress dialog, and once all five services have completed you then go on to start `MainActivity`. Is that right? And, the freeze you mentioned, is that an ANR (i.e. the UI completely stops responding such that the progress dialog is not updated) or just a large delay before `MainActivity` is started?

Comment: Ah, sorry, "implements" should be "has an instance of a `ResultReceiver`" and "passing itself" should be "passing that `ResultReceiver` instance".

Comment: exactly. you got my point bro.. now what happens instead of waiting for process to complete by intent service it goes to main activity.. At the main-activity it freezes the main ui. and fetched/compute other remaining process

Comment: and yes one more point.  it is all intent service is running in sequentially not parallel.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've worked out what the problem is - I've updated my answer. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Answer is perfect explanation of my problem.... so kind of you.... So i have one more question... if I use the requestFuture then my intentservice will execute sequentially. But it is taking approx 20 to 30 sec in fetching my data on wifi. I can't allow user to wait that much of time. is there any way to get rid of my problem.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to create five separate intent service subclasses - as far as I know, each subclass has its own worker thread. Alternatively you could create a custom solution, perhaps using `ExecutorService` and `Runnable` to manage the threading. Naturally, that does increase complexity though.

Comment: right now I am also creating the 5 separate intentservice subclasses.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in `MainActivity`? Do you absolutely have to download all of the data via those 5 intent services before you start the activity? Are you displaying the data that's downloaded in `MainActivity`?

Comment: Not exactly.. on mainactivity there is button. when user is click on this button then download will need. And that button is very crucial to the app and most likely user will click on this as soon as the app open. so I need to fetch data before main activity.

Comment: What exactly does the button do?

Comment: that button plot the graph with the fetched data.

Comment: In terms of UX, at least, it'd probably be easier to start the data download when the application is first started (or the primary activity is started) in order to avoid blocking the UI. If the user does go ahead and tap the button which starts `MainActivity`, you could set up the graph in such a way that it would display whatever data is available and update automatically if new data is made available. If that's not acceptable then you could display the progress dialog in `MainActivity` itself and block until the data is fully downloaded.

Comment: This is particularly so given that you're storing the data that's downloaded in a local database. Consider generating the graph from that database and simply showing a nice little "updating" icon somewhere in the activity while you're doing the data download, and update the graph automatically as data come in (hiding the "updating" icon once you're finished). This is much nicer then blocking the UI completely.

Comment: By the way, if you're happy with my answer to your original question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this will be important, but it might help someone out as i face same problem. I was installing rows(35,000 above records) downloaded from server, it freezed the phone and the UI.

To SOLVE this, i had to put my installation to sqlite code in an AsyncTask, that way it run perfectly without hanging anything.